# How to display same picture on new php page when clicked on the picture?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to show the picture from MySQL.

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="imagedisplay.php"><img src="galleryshow.php?id=' . $row['id'] .'" width="300" height="250" /></td>';
echo '<td><li>Species:'.$row['species'].'</li><li>Age: '.$row['age'].'</li><li>Sex: '.$row['sex'].'</li><li>Date: '.$row['date'].'</li><li>Time: '.$row['time'].'</li><li>Location: '.$row['location'].'</li><li>Comment: '.$row['comment'].'</li></td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

I want display the same picture on `imagedisplay.php`.

Comment: `...<a href="imagedisplay.php?id=' . $row['id'] .'">...` Then retrieve id in imagedisplay.php

Comment: And what is your problem? Get the record of the database in imagedisplay.php and show that like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not much of an answer, since it's not much of a question:

You'll need to pass your $row['id'] as a parameter to your `imagedisplay.php`. Using `GET` it would look something like:

`echo '<td><a href="imagedisplay.php?rowid=' . $row['id'] . "><img src="galleryshow.php?id=' . $row['id'] .'" width="300" height="250" /></a></td>';`

You'll have to pick that variable up in your `imagedisplay.php` code and then use it again like you did here.

Comment: thank you, that alot with my php stater

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at `$_GET` and pass it through as a parameter for `imagedisplay.php`.

Your url should be something like:

```
<a href="imagedisplay.php?image=<?=$row['id'];?>">image_code</a>
```

The main important bit being `?image=<?=$row['id'];?>`

Then, on `imagedisplay.php`

```
<img src="galleryshow.php?=<?=$_GET['image'];?>"/>
```

That should get your image.

However, if this image is literally only being shown on the page and nothing else, you could just have a link to the image so it opens up in browser, or use JavaScript to enlarge on click.